# UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad type letters?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, keyboard, uitextfield

I really want to make a keyboard that is the UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad but instead of it showing a 4 in a textfield when pressing the 4 button,  i want it to highlight the G for about 5 seconds and while its highlighted, if i press again it goes to h then to i, and for all letters, so 2 would start A then b then c if clicked multiple times? i found out on IOS they have a built in one that does this, but its not exactly the UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad and its for japanese, it will show, and type in US but still some japanese around and is hard to use because its not a true full UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad. like 0 is space or go to next letter, not on the japanese one though. so how could i code this for my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do this is to create your own “keyboard” view with the buttons and actions you want, and assign it to the text field's `inputView` property.  Then the system will display your keyboard instead of the normal system keyboard.  The keyboard view (or view controller) will need a reference back to the text field, so it can use the `UITextInput` methods to respond to the user's touches.

[“Custom Views for Data Input” in *Text, Web, and Editing Programming Guide for iOS*](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH12-SW1)
[*UITextInput Protocol Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInput_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInput)

Comment: Not really what i had in mind, if you see old phones like, i guess nokia? old one, where its a screen and all numbers, in text, you press 2 and it goes to a that is highlighted, then after about 5 seconds it goes away, pound is space i think, and so on and just tap letters, theres a build in keyboard in system that does this, its japanese though and you can get american, although it doesn't have that spacing and buttons, instead click two buttons to change words or the word is all caps because of the dictionary for the japanese keyboard, which can't turn off.

Comment: Yes, I know what you're talking about.  You could build that system using the APIs I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good approach, but technically you can. Work not with keyboards, but with input fields. I mean that, for example, [`UITextViewDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html) defines `–textView:shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` method. When user tries to change text in `UITextView`, this method will be called. Then you can change text manually and return NO to ignore user input.

In example below when user types '0', 'G' will be added instead (to illustrate my idea).

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSString *correctReplacement = [text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"0" withString:@"G"];
    textView.text = [textView.text stringByAppendingString:correctReplacement];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: thanks! this is kind of close, but i can't use it because if that works with one letters, the old phones give you about 5 seconds and if you press 2 again, the letter changes and goes around. but i think i can make that code work if i use an array and it goes around the array for a given time.. hope that works:]

Comment: Hmm. I've understood what you want. And gave code not for solving your problem, but to illustrate `UITextViewDelegate` usage (cause code for your problem is much more complex). To solve your problem, you should, for exapmle, add some variables like "last tapped key" & "last key taps count" and clear these values after timer is fired. Something like this.